# My Sprite Kit button won't work in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, osx-yosemite

Hi than you for looking at this i was wondering why my code in swift sprite kit won't work i can run it but when i click on the button it does not work(it does not go to the scene) but when i add a println to the if statement and then i click it it does run the println. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code for my first scene:

```
    //
//  GameScene.swift
//  Pocket Rocket
//
//  Created by Lucas Farleigh on 11/11/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Lucas Farleigh. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit;

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"background")
    let playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playbutton")
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
        background.yScale = 2
        background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
    self.addChild(background)
        self.addChild(playButton)

    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        //making the scene vars
        var scene =  PlayScene(size: self.size)


        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
             let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
            let skview = self.view as  SKView!
            scene.size = skview.bounds.size
            playButton.name = "PB"


            if node.name == "PB"{
                println("it worked")
                skview.presentScene(scene)
            }


        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

And my second scene(playscene)

```
    //
//  PlayScene.swift
//  Pocket Rocket
//
//  Created by Lucas Farleigh on 14/11/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Lucas Farleigh. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit
import UIKit
import Foundation

class PlayScene:SKScene{
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")

    let bar1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Bar1")


    let bar2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Bar2")

    let bar3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Bar3")


    let bar4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Bar4")

    let bar5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Bar5")

    let bar6 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Bar6")


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
        addChild(background)
        background.yScale = 2
```

Comment: Please show the version of the code with the `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you are creating `background` and `PlayButton` nodes twice:  once as a class property, and a second time as a local variable in `didMoveToView`.  It is the local version that you are then adding to the scene as a child view.  If you want to be able to test against these nodes in other methods in your class, get rid of the local declarations in `didMoveToView`.  You can still fill in the other information about these nodes, just remove the `let` statements.

Then in your `touchesBegan` you want to get the location of the touch in the scene by passing `self` to `touch.locationInNode(self)` and then retrieve the node that corresponds to that touch:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if node == Play_Button {
            println("Hello!!!!")
        }
    }
}
```

---

A second way to accomplish the `PlayButton` would be to give the node a name when you create it:

```
Play_Button.name = "playButton"
```

and then your `touchesBegan` would look like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if node.name == "playButton" {
            println("Hello!!!!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wait it gave me an error this is the error on line 49 it sais "[anyObject] does not have a member named name"

Comment: I think you accidentally called `nodesAtPoint` which returns `[AnyObject]`.  You should call instead `nodeAtPoint` which returns a `SKNode`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with vacawama's answer (I use the naming option) but I'd like to add a little on my approach to buttons in SK.  Usually you either have a background and a label or just a PNG image with both background and label.

[image]

When using *nodeAtPoint* on the label you might not have enough area.  If instead you use the background area to detect taps then you might have conflicts with the label on top of the node.

[image]

To solve this I create a third element (usually an *SKShapeNode*) on top of both, transparent and a little bigger to make it easier for the user to tap on it.

[image]

To make sure you are positioning these tap areas on top of the buttons remember to use a higher *zPosition*

[image]